# How do I make sure images embedded in R markdown code are compiled to the right place in the output document?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to include some DAGs in the PDF file that I am compiling my R Markdown output to. However, after compiling, the DAGs do not show up where they are in the code/ are in the wrong order and do not 'go with' the right questions. How do I specify where in the document I want the image to be inserted?

I have tried different ways of embedding them but this seems to be what works best, except for the order.

This is the syntax I'm using: ! [DAG 1] (/Users/user1/Desktop/1dag.png). I am typing this after my regular text where I would want the picture to appear.

There is no error message, but the pictures are not showing up where expected in the output file.

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101725/latex-figures-appear-before-text-in-pandoc-markdown

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of threads on this subject if you search through stackoverflow, but to quote an answer [straight from the source (i.e. rmarkdown manual)](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html#figures):

> PDF documents are generated through the LaTeX files generated from R Markdown. A highly surprising fact to LaTeX beginners is that figures float by default: even if you generate a plot in a code chunk on the first page, the whole figure environment may float to the next page. This is just how LaTeX works by default. It has a tendency to float figures to the top or bottom of pages. Although it can be annoying and distracting, we recommend that you refrain from playing the “Whac-A-Mole” game in the beginning of your writing, i.e., desparately trying to position figures “correctly” while they seem to be always dodging you. You may wish to fine-tune the positions once the content is complete using the `fig.pos` chunk option (e.g., `fig.pos = 'h'`). See https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Positioning_images_and_tables for possible values of fig.pos and more general tips about this behavior in LaTeX. In short, this can be a difficult problem for PDF output.

If they images are too big and get floated because there's not enough space on the page, you could also try resizing them as well. There's more info on how to change the figure dimensions, alignments and aspect ratios on the [bookdown manual](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html).